# Cannot cancel form submission in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to cancel form submission after button click.
When button is clicked i get some information from check-timetable-timing-conflict with json.
So i decide to cancel the form submission if the data coming with json is 1.
But it does not cancel form submission although i get 1.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="subform" name="subform">
...
...

<button id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return select_course();">{% trans "EKLE" %}</button>
...
...

<script>
conflict = 0;

var select_course = function()
{
    //alert("button clicked");
    var selectcourse = document.getElementById('kurskod');
    var kurskod = selectcourse.options[selectcourse.selectedIndex].value;    
    var selectcoursedate = document.getElementById('kursgunu');
    var kursgunu = selectcoursedate.options[selectcoursedate.selectedIndex].value;    
    var selectcoursestart = document.getElementById('kursbasla');
    var kursbasla = selectcoursestart.value;
    var selectcourseend = document.getElementById('kursbitis');
    var kursbitis = selectcourseend.value;

    check_conflict(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis)
}

var check_conflict = function(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis) {
    $.get('/check-timetable-timing-conflict', {kurskod: kurskod, kursgunu: kursgunu, kursbasla: kursbasla, kursbitis: kursbitis}, function(data){
        objlist = JSON.parse(data);
        if (objlist[0] == 1) {
            conflict = 1;
            alert("Confictval:"+conflict);
            var warning = document.getElementById('warningdiv');
            warning.innerHTML = "Başka bir kurs ile Saat çakışması var.";

            $('#subform').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('prevent submit');             
            });            
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you get the alerts `Confictval: ` and `prevent submit` ?

Comment: I only get Conflictval alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of asynchronous behaivor of ajax.
When i click the button, the form submission already starts.
So when i try to check the conflict condition in jquery the form submission has already finished. So i solved the problem by submitting the form just in the if condition in jquery where i get conflict=1 with document.subform.submit().

Before the solution, i was starting the form submission, then i was doing jquery checks.
But now i first make jquery checks, then i do or not do form submission according to jquery search results.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="subform" name="subform">
...
...

#DELETED THIS > <button id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return select_course();">{% trans "EKLE" %}</button>
#ADDED THIS > <a href="#" onclick="return select_course();">EKLE</a>
...
...

<script>
conflict = 0;
var select_course = function()
{
    //alert("button clicked");
    var selectcourse = document.getElementById('kurskod');
    var kurskod = selectcourse.options[selectcourse.selectedIndex].value;    
    var selectcoursedate = document.getElementById('kursgunu');
    var kursgunu = selectcoursedate.options[selectcoursedate.selectedIndex].value;    
    var selectcoursestart = document.getElementById('kursbasla');
    var kursbasla = selectcoursestart.value;
    var selectcourseend = document.getElementById('kursbitis');
    var kursbitis = selectcourseend.value;

    check_conflict(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis)
}

var check_conflict = function(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis) {
    $.get('/check-timetable-timing-conflict', {kurskod: kurskod, kursgunu: kursgunu, kursbasla: kursbasla, kursbitis: kursbitis}, function(data){
        objlist = JSON.parse(data);
        if (objlist[0] == 1) {
            conflict = 1;
            alert("Confictval:"+conflict);
            var warning = document.getElementById('warningdiv');
            warning.innerHTML = "Başka bir kurs ile Saat çakışması var.";         
        } else {
            document.subform.submit();  #ADDED THIS PART  
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the `form` from submitting you need to return `false` from the `onclick` function that is called when the `button` is clicked. Also to prevent `ajax` `form` submissions you can also add `e.preventDefault();` like below.

**Note:** The same effect could be achieved if using the form's `onsubmit` method instead of the button's `onclick` method to call the function.

```js
var select_course = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your logic goes here
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form role="form" method="POST" id="subform" name="subform" >
    <button id="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return select_course(event);">placeholder</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is where the submit event listener is set up.

You need to move this block of code outside the `check_conflict()` function.

```
$('#subform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('prevent submit');             
});
```

`.submit(function(e){})` creates a handler for the submit event. In your code, you  aren't creating the handler until after the check_conflict function makes it's asynchronous call returns. It's too late. You need the handler already in place when the user submits the form.

```
<script>

    conflict = 0;
    $('#subform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('prevent submit');             
    });   

    var select_course = function()
    {
        var selectcourse = document.getElementById('kurskod');
        var kurskod = selectcourse.options[selectcourse.selectedIndex].value;    
        var selectcoursedate = document.getElementById('kursgunu');
        var kursgunu = selectcoursedate.options[selectcoursedate.selectedIndex].value;    
        var selectcoursestart = document.getElementById('kursbasla');
        var kursbasla = selectcoursestart.value;
        var selectcourseend = document.getElementById('kursbitis');
        var kursbitis = selectcourseend.value;

        check_conflict(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis)
    }

    var check_conflict = function(kurskod,kursgunu,kursbasla,kursbitis) {
        $.get('/check-timetable-timing-conflict', {kurskod: kurskod, kursgunu: kursgunu, kursbasla: kursbasla, kursbitis: kursbitis}, function(data){
            objlist = JSON.parse(data);
            if (objlist[0] == 1) {
                conflict = 1;
                alert("Confictval:"+conflict);
                var warning = document.getElementById('warningdiv');
                warning.innerHTML = "Başka bir kurs ile Saat çakışması var.";         
            }
            else {
                // todo no conflict
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: i want to cancel form submit "if (objlist[0] == 1)". If i take the block out of if statement how can i check when will i cancel submit form. Because it should submit if conflict=0, i sould cancel if conflict=1

Comment: @ivbtar You cannot do that exactly. Your check is asynchronous but the form submit happens immediately. What you must do is prevent the form submit from doing anything, make the ajax call to do the validation, then proceed if it's valid. You might want to refactor so that instead of two ajax calls (validate and save), it completes the save or returns validation errors.

Comment: Hi AndrewR. You are right. I stopped posting form on button click. Now i am posting the form directly in jquery in if statement, where i decide to send or not send the form.